# problem with cup products

Tags: group-cohomology

I have been reading Class field theory by JS Milne http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf, and im stuck on the chapter about group cohomology and would like some hints, specifically about cup products, on page 79 he has remark 3.5 which goes as follows:

Let G be a finite cyclic group and let $m$ by its size, now let $\gamma \in H^2(G,\mathbb{Z})$, correspond under the isomorphism $ H^2(G,\mathbb{Z}) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(G,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ to the map sending the generator $\sigma \in G$ to $1/m$. Then the map $H^r(G,M) \rightarrow H^{r+2}(G,M)$ is $x \mapsto x \cup \gamma$. (note these are tate groups not just cohomology groups).

I wanted to prove this, but im not quite sure how, I think I need some clarification on how cup products work.

Thank you

Comment: You are trying to prove that "*the map*" is equal to $x \mapsto x \cup \gamma$.  But what is "the map"?

Comment: He means that the periodicity isomorphism is given by the cup-product (because any finite cyclic group is periodic of order 2).  To the OP: Check out Ken Brown's classic textbook.

Comment: Is this isomorphism in some sense related to the duality theorems? Or is it just a dellusion?

Answer (score 2):

Serre Local Fields, VIII, Section 4 gives the following hint: 'the period isomorphisms are given by cup product with theta: this follows, for example, from the formulas for the cup product given in Cartan-Eilenberg (Homological Algebra) p. 252." Another place to look is Weiss, Cohomology of Groups.